# Slow session: fastest way to check if a document exists

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a simpler session (haskell driver if it matters) with mongodb backend. I may be wrong but it seems a bit slow compared to when I run the bench without the session.
With session it gives me 25 connections a second - 10596 without.

Once the session is set on the initial load, all it does is compares the SID from cookie to the SID stored in session document in mongodb. So on every request it does a single trip to the database server. I get the SID from cookie and check if a document with such SID exist in mongodb. That's all. I am learning, so my session logic could be off too.

At the moment, I use `count` to check if the document exist. I count documents with relevant SID and test if it == 1. Is this a fast enough way to check if document exist?

I found in this document [test if document exists](https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) that testing with `find` and `limit` is faster. But it only compares it to `findOne` - not to `count`.

So my question is: what is the fastest way to check if a document exist?

Thanks.

Comment: how many data are there in your collection? Have you build an index on the field SID?

Comment: Well, since I am the only one connecting to the server then it is only one session entry - one session document. The number of documents will equal the number of connected users with sessions. Maybe benchmarking tool creates a new session for every connection, ,that's why it is so slow. But regardless of my session issue, I would still be interested in generic answer on the fastest way to check if document exists.

Comment: if you look into the source code of find/findOne/count, you'll know the difference:
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.count
function ( x ){
    return this.find( x ).count();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your question, have a look at the source code of find/findOne/count

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.count
function ( x ){
    return this.find( x ).count();
}
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.findOne
function ( query , fields, options ){
    var cursor = this.find(query, fields, -1 /* limit */, 0 /* skip*/,
        0 /* batchSize */, options);

    if ( ! cursor.hasNext() )
        return null;
    var ret = cursor.next();
    if ( cursor.hasNext() ) throw "findOne has more than 1 result!";
    if ( ret.$err )
        throw "error " + tojson( ret );
    return ret;
}
rs0:PRIMARY> db.geo.find
function ( query , fields , limit , skip, batchSize, options ){
    var cursor = new DBQuery( this._mongo , this._db , this ,
                        this._fullName , this._massageObject( query ) , fields , limit , skip , batchSize , options || this.getQueryOptions() );

    var connObj = this.getMongo();
    var readPrefMode = connObj.getReadPrefMode();
    if (readPrefMode != null) {
        cursor.readPref(readPrefMode, connObj.getReadPrefTagSet());
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

The difference is, findOne/count uses something from this.find, while find uses DBQuery.
So I did a benchmark on the 3 ways:

```
  function benchMark1() {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        db.zips.find({
            "_id": "35004"
        }, {
            _id: 1
        });
    }
    print(new Date() - date);
}

function benchMark2() {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        db.zips.findOne({
            "_id": "35004"
        }, {
            _id: 1
        });
    }
    print(new Date() - date);
}

function benchMark3() {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        db.zips.count({
            "_id": "35004"
        }, {
            _id: 1
        });
    }
    print(new Date() - date);
}
```

It turns out benchMark1 takes 1046ms, 2 takes 37611ms, 3 takes 63306ms.
It seems you are using the worst one.
**EDIT: The reason why it's slow is described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls**

What else, make sure you have an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the field SID:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.system.indexes.find()
```

If no index exists on SID,

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.session.ensureIndex({SID: 1}, {unique: true}) // change "session" to your collection name
```

Note that although _id is usually an ObjectId, it doesn't have to be. So you can use the SID as _id. And there's already an index on it so that you can save an index and thus make the insertion faster. To do this, just set the _id field to SID when you insert a record.

```
{
  _id: [value of SID]
  ... // rest of record
}
```

And if this still doesn't meat your requirements, you need to try analyse where the bottleneck is. That's another topic we can talk about if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test with the indexing. At the moment index is on '_id'. So is it appropriate to test for documents existence with `count`?

Comment: I add a benchMark above, it turns out the count is the slowest one. have a look.

Comment: OK. This pretty much answers the question. You get the tick . Thanks.